# Benefits of using backbone.js vs php mvc framework

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, cakephp, backbone.js

I've been learning Codeigniter, and someone suggested I look into backbone.js instead. The issue is that I can't find an answer as to why I should use backbone instead of sticking with CS, or another php mvc framework like cakePHP. It seems that backbone is much more bulky, and the syncing with a database thing seems overly complex.

Can someone give some insight into why one would want to use backbone.js?

Comment: backbone is great for single page applications that talk to rest based services.

Comment: codeigniter and backbone have different goals.

Comment: Can the close crew NOT close this question? Please? This is a legitimate question that newbies could find useful. It is not surprising that there is confusion between these two frameworks and what their respective purposes are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't "sync" backbone with a database. Backbone provides a framework on which you can build a UI which will then interact with some other type of interface that talks to the db (like a php/java/.net/whatever app).

Many people use a framework like CI to build that other interface/API.

[There even is a RESTful fork of CI for a purpose just like this](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver).